# Filling in remaining kwargs with unittest.mock.ANY

Tags: python-3.x, mocking, arguments, pytest

Let's say I have class `Foo` with method `bar`:

```
class Foo:
    # ...
   
    def bar(self, **kwargs):
        # do something important with kwargs["important_arg"]
```

Now I want to test this and I use the following approach:

```
mock_foo = Mock()
mock_foo.bar(important_arg="hello", unimportant_arg="world")
```

I only care that `important_arg` was `"hello"`, other args don't matter. But

```
mock.assert_called_with(important_arg="hello", **ANY)
```

fails (at least in `pytest`) with:

```
TypeError: pytest_mock.plugin.wrap_assert_called_with() argument after ** must be a mapping, not _ANY
```

What is the correct way to express:

> The method must be called such that keyword parameter `important_arg` was given as `"hello"`; I don't care about other keyword args

? Or do I have to dig in `call_args`?

Answer (score 3):

The way I solved this was by digging into call args. For example:

```
mock.assert_called_once()
assert 'important_arg' in mock.call_args.kwargs
assert mock.call_args.kwargs['important_arg'] == 'hello'
```